# How to measure the angle of the tangent to an ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

If we consider the ellipse in the picture here

[image]

How do we determine the angle $\lambda$ of the vector v (tangent at point x = 2 ,y = 3) with the line joining the center (10,0)and the point (2,3)?

Edit:

a = 10, b = 5

it seems impossible it is 80°, it looks more like 56-57°

Comment: Can you elaborate the details, like the major axis length and minor axis length etc. and this question is to be asked in Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: ... and I see the exact same question+figure there.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET I don't feel that coordinates should be marked like this. That's why asked those details specifically.

Comment: I meant: this post has been posted on 2 groups: physics and maths. which is evil, to me.

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy, a is 10 and b is 5, how do you mark coordinates properly?

Comment: Corrected your typo $ (0,10) \rightarrow (10,0) $, ok?

Comment: I get the angle at about $54.25^\circ$. I don't have time to post a solution now, but I will later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+ \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} =1 $$

Differentiate to find slope

$$ y^{'}= \dfrac{x\,  b^2 }{y\, a^2 }= \dfrac{8\, 5^2 }{3 \,10^2} = \dfrac23 $$

Find arctan of above and *add* to $ {20.55}^0  $ to get correct angle.

Answer (score -1):

The angle $ \lambda $ is: 90°- 9.46° = 80.54°.

If you look closely you can see that the angle $ \lambda $ is not measured from the line joining the center of the ellipse to the point (the green line), but from the line joining the apopsis to the point (the red line).

The angle of the velocity vector is:
$$  \arctan\left( \frac{ e + \cos(\nu)}{ \sin(\nu)} \right) = 39.44\!° $$

where e is the eccentricity, and $\nu$ is the true anomaly $( e = \frac{ \sqrt{3} }{2} ; \ \ \nu = 92.52\!° )$.

The angle of the the line joining the center [10,0] and the point [2,3] ([10,0]-[2,3]=[8,-3]) is: 
$$ \arctan \left( -\frac38 \right) = -20.56 \!° $$
So the angle between that line and the tangent vector is: 39.44° + 20.56° = 60°.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, are you sure? the angle seems a lot smaller